# Queries and linked tables

Tags: database, split

I split my database (Name1), and everything was working fine. I then saved Name1_be.accdb to Name2_be.accdb and Name1.accdb to Name2.accdb.

Now my queries are not picking up any data in Name2.accdb. I have relinked the tables in Name2.accdb, but it's like the accdb is not seeing the tables in the _be.accdb, even though all the names are the same as they were before the save as?

Have I royally messed this up or is there something simple I am missing?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This is a database admin question, you should see on the DB stack site.  But you will need to put more details.  What database engine?  Versions?  How did you split?  Commands?

Comment: Ah... OK :-)

Got it sorted, thanks :-)